# jquery function variables not working

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make this function work, but im not getting it. The counter is not working, and i want it to make the first condition of the function. Also im unable to reach the second condition. It always goes to the first condition.

This is the jquery code:

```
var cpcounter1 = 0;
var cpcounter2 = 0;
var inpreco = ["", ""];
var inprocess = ["", ""];

$(".opcaopreco1").click(function () {
    Arra(this, "#preco", inpreco, "cpindex1" ,"cpactive1", cpcounter1, "preco");
});
$(".opcaopreco2").click(function () {
    Arra(this, "#process", inprocess, "cpindex2", "cpactive2", cpcounter2, "process");
});
function Arra(element, input, inpArray, secIndex, inpActive, counter, msqlip) {
    var inpValue = $("#" + element.id).val();      
    var inpActive = $("#" + element.id).data(inpActive);
    var secIndex = $("#" + element.id).data(secIndex);

    if (counter==0){
        inpArray[0] = (inpValue);
        $("#z1").html("result1");  
    }else
    if (inpActive=="") {
        inpArray[secIndex]=(" OR "+msqlip+" BETWEEN "+inpValue);        
        $("#z1").html("result2");                  
    }
    counter++;
    $(input).val(inpArray[0]+inpArray[1]);   
    $("#z2").html(counter);       
};
```

this is the html code:

```
<input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='1 AND 5000'><br><br>
    <input id="process" type="text" name="process" value='1 AND 11'><br><br>
    <div id="op1l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op1" class="opcaopreco1" value="Start" data-cpindex1="1" data-cpactive1="Test1">
        <label for="op1"></label>
        <span class="itext">Test1</span>
    </div>      
    <div id="op2l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op2" class="opcaopreco1" value="Start2" data-cpindex1="2" data-cpactive1="Test2">
        <label for="op2"></label>
        <span class="itext">Test2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="op3l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op3" class="opcaopreco2" value="Start3" data-cpindex2="1" data-cpactive2="Test3">
        <label for="op3"></label>
        <span class="itext">Test1</span>
    </div>      
    <div id="op4l" class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="op4" class="opcaopreco2" value="Start4" data-cpindex2="2" data-cpactive2="Test4">
        <label for="op4"></label>
        <span class="itext">Test2</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="z">
        <li id="z1">z1</li>         
        <li id="z2">z2</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It looks like you are incrementing on "counter" but every time the function is called "counter" is set by var cpcounter1 or cpcounter2 which are never changed so counter will always be 0 and your condition is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ew2r3ytb/

```js
var cpcounter1 = 0;
var cpcounter2 = 0;
var inpreco = ["", ""];
var inprocess = ["", ""];

$(".opcaopreco1").click(function () {
    cpcounter1 = Arra(this, "#preco", inpreco, "cpindex1" ,"cpactive1", cpcounter1, "preco");
});
$(".opcaopreco2").click(function () {
    cpcounter2 = Arra(this, "#process", inprocess, "cpindex2", "cpactive2", cpcounter2, "process");
});
function Arra(element, input, inpArray, secIndex, inpActive, counter, msqlip) {
  var inpValue = $("#" + element.id).val();      
  var inpActive = $("#" + element.id).data(inpActive);
  var secIndex = $("#" + element.id).data(secIndex);
  if (counter == 0){
    inpArray[0] = (inpValue);
    $("#z1").html("result1");  
  }else if (inpActive=="") {
    inpArray[secIndex]=(" OR "+msqlip+" BETWEEN "+inpValue);        
    $("#z1").html("result2");                  
  }
  counter++;
  $(input).val(inpArray[0]+inpArray[1]);   
  $("#z2").html(counter);       
  return counter;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='1 AND 5000'><br><br>
<input id="process" type="text" name="process" value='1 AND 11'><br><br>
<div id="op1l" class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="op1" class="opcaopreco1" value="Start" data-cpindex1="1" data-cpactive1="Test1">
    <label for="op1"></label>
    <span class="itext">Test1</span>
</div>      
<div id="op2l" class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="op2" class="opcaopreco1" value="Start2" data-cpindex1="2" data-cpactive1="Test2">
    <label for="op2"></label>
    <span class="itext">Test2</span>
</div>
<div id="op3l" class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="op3" class="opcaopreco2" value="Start3" data-cpindex2="1" data-cpactive2="Test3">
    <label for="op3"></label>
    <span class="itext">Test1</span>
</div>      
<div id="op4l" class="input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="op4" class="opcaopreco2" value="Start4" data-cpindex2="2" data-cpactive2="Test4">
    <label for="op4"></label>
    <span class="itext">Test2</span>
</div>
<ul id="z">
    <li id="z1">z1</li>         
    <li id="z2">z2</li>
</ul>
```

You need to return the counter value & capture the value where you have called the `Arra` method.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Doesnt solve all problems but its a path to a solution